# How use a button inside a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to use 4 fragments

[F1]

[F2][F3][F4]

F1 will have 3 buttons to change between F2,F3 and F4 but i don´t know how to use the buttons properties like in a normal Activity

That's what i have in my F1 code

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_01, container, false);

}
```

Comment: Use the same approach like in normal activity.

Answer (score 6):

Check this :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_01, container, false);
    // here you have the reference of your button
    Button yourButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.your_button_id);
    return view;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get the view first, and then get the button from the view
like this:

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_01, container, false);
Button btn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn);
```

You should do some tutoriasl first, its not that hard.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_01, container, false);
    Button firstButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.firstbutton);

    Button seconButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.seconbutton);

    Button thirdButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.thirdbutton);
    return view;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);


        Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonSayHi);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                onButtonClicked(v);
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

  public void onButtonClicked(View view)
  {
          //do your stuff here..           
    final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
    ft.replace(R.id.frameLayoutFragmentContainer, new FragmentTwo(), "NewFragmentTag"); 
    ft.commit(); 

    ft.addToBackStack(null);    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple way to reference a button or any widget in a fragment.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_one, container, false);

        btnOne = view.findViewById(R.id.btnOne);

return view;
```